# unity3d пустая сцена в откомпилированом проекте

Tags: unity3d, компиляция

Создал сцену в юнити 3д с главной камеры её видно при запуске работает, но в скомпилированном проекте нету ничего. картинка 2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сцена появилась в билде, надо добавить её в список сцен.
File > Build settings
[добавить тут](https://pasteboard.co/HmDsA3K.png)

Comment: Добавлять нужно в настройках там где нужно выбрать платформу, linux windows итд